# Reflexivity, James' theorem and a strengthening of a theorem of Riesz

Tags: functional-analysis, reflexive-space

Let us consider only Banach spaces.

A classical theorem of Riesz says that for every proper closed subspace $Y$ of a Banach space $X$ there is a sequence of vectors $x_n\in X$ with $\Vert x_n\Vert=1$ for all $n$ and such that $\Vert x_n+Y\Vert\to 1$, where this latter norm is the usual norm in the quotient space $X/\!Y$: $$\Vert x+Y\Vert=\inf_{y\in Y}\Vert x+y\Vert.$$

I will call the validity of the natural strengthening of this theorem the **strong Riesz property** (SRP):

> A Banach space has the **SRP** iff for every proper closed subspace $Y$ of $X$, there is $x\in X$ with $\Vert x\Vert=\Vert x+Y\Vert=1$.

Two applications of Hahn-Banach (on $X$ and on the dual $X^*$) imply that every reflexive space has the SRP.

A closely related property is given by James' theorem, which I will also expres as a property:

> A Banach space $X$ has **James' property** (**JP**) iff for every continuous linear functional $f\in X^*$ attains its norm at some unit vector; i.e., there exists $x\in X$ with $\Vert x\Vert=1$ such that $|f(x)|=1$.

James' theorem states that JP and reflexivity are equivalent.

I would like to know whether reflexivity and the SRP are equivalent. It seems that passing through JP would be a natural way to prove it.

The implications (reflexivity)$\Rightarrow$(JP)$\Rightarrow$(SRP) are easy. For example, the last one: Let $Y$ be a proper closed subspace of a Banach space with JP. By Hahn-Banach, take $f\in X^*$ with $f(Y)=0$ and $\Vert f\Vert=1$. By JP, take $x\in X$ with $\Vert x\Vert=|f(x)|=1$. Then
$$\Vert x+Y\Vert\leq\Vert x\Vert=1=|f(x)|=\inf_y|f(x+y)|\leq\inf_y\Vert x+y\Vert=\Vert x+Y\Vert,$$
which yields SRP.

The "obvious way" to prove the converse would be: Assume $f\in X^*$ has norm $1$. By SRP, take $x\in X$ with $\Vert x\Vert=\Vert x+\ker(f)\Vert=1$. Then proceed to prove that $|f(x)|=1$.

However, this very last step does not seem to be valid, or at least not in any easy manner. Everything that I could obtain is that $|f(x)|\leq 1$.

> tl;dr **Does SRP as above imply reflexivity**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The "obvious way" to prove the converse would be: Assume $f\in X^*$ is
> nonzero. By SRP, take $x\in X$ with $\Vert x\Vert=\Vert
> x+\ker(f)\Vert=1$. Then proceed to prove that $|f(x)|=1$.

I suppose  the OP forgot to require  that $\|f\|=1$, above.  Assuming this, one has for every $y$ in $X$ that
$$
  k:=f(x)y-f(y)x\in \ker(f).
  $$
Therefore
$$
  |f(y)| =
  |f(y)| \|x+\ker(f)\| =
  \|f(y)x+\ker(f) \| = $$$$ =
  \|f(x)y+\ker(f)\| \leq 
  |f(x)|\|y\|.
  $$
So,
$$
  1 = \|f\| = \sup_{\|y\|\leq 1}|f(y)| \leq  |f(x)| \leq \|f\|\|x\| = 1.
  $$